# can you "voice to text" without using wifi or data

Tags: voice-recognition

Is there a way or app that allows  "voice to text" when I am not near wifi or have data?

Answer (score 6):

For the most part, sure.

I just put my Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.2.2) into Airplane mode and tried to compose an email message with speech-to-text.

It worked, but it was slo-o-o-o-w. And not as accurate as I'd like.

If you go into `Settings > Language & input > Google voice typing (settings)` you can set which languages are downloaded to your device for speech-to-text. English is my default (and is already downloaded) but I see about 20 other files I can download.

However, whether you can do this or how well it works depends a lot (I think) on your device and the version of the OS you're running.

Comment: It really does depend as I put my phone into airplane mode and it was very fast at picking up my speech and very accurate.

Comment: Any information on the privacy policy when using this offline? IS the data transmitted later when going online?

Comment: "I think it depends..." is not an answer.